# Apex Oracle Application Express is not sending e-mails, It just puts them in queue

Tags: oracle-apex

I am trying to make a forgot password reset in APEX Oracle Application Express. Idea is that I can enter user e-mail address and send to it new e-mail with link for a reset password page.

I used SEND.MAIL in PL/SQL as in APEX documentation.

```
 APEX_MAIL.SEND(
        p_to        => :P5_EMAIL,
        p_from      => '**********@gmail.com',
        p_subj      => 'Promjena lozinke',
        p_body      => 'Klikni na poveznicu za promjenu lozinke.',
        p_body_html => 'Klikni na poveznicu za promjenu lozinke. <a href=''> Promjena lozinke </a>');
```

When I press a send button on my UI it puts that action in sending emails queue but I don't receive any e-mail nor it sends them at all.

[See the queue here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRHnf.png)

I think that it is the configuration settings problem. Something is wrong with communication between mail and APEX.
I tried login to Administrator account -> Manage Instance -> Instance Settings -> Email -> at first my SMTP Host Port was 587 and it didn't work. I have set it now to default 25 and it is still not working [See the settings here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VU4yb.png)

I don't get any visible errors so I do not know what is wrong and what setting I should change. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Add yet another *line* into your code:

```
apex_mail.send(...);

apex_mail.push_queue;           --> this
```

(That procedure accepts two optional parameters: host name and port number. See documentation for more info. Add them if you have to).

Comment: I added this but still nothing. I also tried going to Administrator account -> Mail Queue and pressed buttons Send all mail and  Force send all mail and still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

First check the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/apex/23.1/aeadm/configuring-email.html#GUID-3F10A06B-69F0-4B4E-BA05-8E315DD1E6DA) and see if everything is configured right.

Maybe your error is not related to Oracle APEX. Is the SMTP server hosted on the machine? Did you try [telnet](https://cyberpanel.net/blog/test-smtp-connection/)?

You could try as SYSDBA or APEX_* to [validate your configuration](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/apex/23.1/aeapi/VALIDATE_EMAIL_CONFIG-Procedure.html#GUID-6367C7AE-AF48-42A6-AA60-951B055B244D):

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
BEGIN
    APEX_INSTANCE_ADMIN.VALIDATE_EMAIL_CONFIG;
END;
```